# Динамическое обновление ListView после POST-запроса

Tags: android, mysql

Здравствуйте. Приложение обращается к серверу POST-запросом, получая от него JSON с некоторыми данными из БД. Этот JSON парсится и записывается в ListView (**пока что ListView обновляется полностью, а не записываются только новые элементы в него. ListView содержит в себе список с сообщениями ОТ и ДЛЯ пользователя. POST-запрос вызывает SELECT * из таблицы с сообщениями, где author='$username', client='$friend'**). Так вот,
хочется, чтобы пока был открыт активити с ListView, его обновление, т.е. вызов POST-запроса на сервер происходил динамически. Как это можно сделать? С помощью обычного Thread'a, вызывая POST-запрос каждые, например, 3 секунды? 
(я так уже сделал, но приложение очень быстро умирает)

Comment: и почему оно падает? код покажите, может ошибки какие есть ?

Comment: почему-то выпадает NPE в том месте, где я присваиваю ListView адаптер. Бывает еще NetworkException

Comment: если ты хочешь сделать чат, то выполнять запросы каждые 3 секунды, чтобы узнать есть ли новые сообщения - это полнейшая чушь. Для таких действий можно воспользоваться сокетами.

Comment: если у вас выпадает NPE и NetworkException то почему этого нету в вопросе? И да, как советует товарищ  Nikotin N : для этого лучше использовать сокеты

Comment: Ну или Firebase cloud message , как вариант

Comment: Вот годный туториал http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/ правда вместо GCM теперь FCM, но это детали!